# Handling exceptions raised in a Ruby thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, exception

I am looking for a solution of classic problem of exception handling. Consider following piece of code:

```
def foo(n)
  puts " for #{n}"
  sleep n
  raise "after #{n}"
end

begin
  threads = []
  [5, 15, 20, 3].each do |i|
    threads << Thread.new do
      foo(i)
    end
  end

  threads.each(&:join)      
rescue Exception => e
  puts "EXCEPTION: #{e.inspect}"
  puts "MESSAGE: #{e.message}"
end
```

This code catches the exception after 5 seconds.

But if I change the array as `[15, 5, 20, 3]`, above code catch the exception after 15 seconds. In short, it always catch the exception raised in first thread.

Any idea, why so. Why doesn't it catch the exception after 3 seconds each time? How do I catch the first raised exception by any thread?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you want any unhandled exception in any thread to cause the interpreter to exit, you need to set [Thread::abort_on_exception=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-c-abort_on_exception-3D) to `true`. Unhandled exception cause the thread to stop running. If you don't set this variable to true, exception will only be raised when you call `Thread#join` or `Thread#value` for the thread. If set to true it will be raised when it occurs and will propagate to the main thread.

```
Thread.abort_on_exception=true # add this

def foo(n)
    puts " for #{n}"
    sleep n
    raise "after #{n}"
end

begin
    threads = []
    [15, 5, 20, 3].each do |i|
        threads << Thread.new do
            foo(i)
        end
    end
    threads.each(&:join)

rescue Exception => e

    puts "EXCEPTION: #{e.inspect}"
    puts "MESSAGE: #{e.message}"
end
```

Output:

```
 for 5
 for 20
 for 3
 for 15
EXCEPTION: #<RuntimeError: after 3>
MESSAGE: after 3
```

Note: but if you want any particular thread instance to raise exception this way there are similar [abort_on_exception= Thread instance method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-abort_on_exception):

```
t = Thread.new {
   # do something and raise exception
}
t.abort_on_exception = true

# Alternatively use Thread.current.abort_on_exception= 
# as first line within thread to ensure it is set before
# any other work is done by the thread.
t = Thread.new {
   Thread.current.abort_on_exception = true
   # do something and raise exception
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I knew about abort_on_exception flag. But my requirement is to know which is the first thread to raise exception and then make some decisions on it.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal, I don't get you last comment. You will catch the first exception (from thread with sleep 3) in the `rescue` clause and here you can make your decision about it. All the rest threads will continue to run if your main thread will not exit after the first exception.

Comment: So this was a test code. My question was how will I catch the first exception thrown from any thread. Any thread can throw exception any time.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal, and this is why you need to make sure child threads run in the context of main thread's `begin-rescue-end` clause. In turn you may want to catch exceptions inside the thread and make your decision here. Possibly it will require [synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29#Thread_or_process_synchronization) if threads will share some state.

Comment: You don't need to wrap the entire thread body in `begin`-`rescue`-`end` clause; all the exceptions will be re-raised at `Thread#join`.

Comment: `Thread.abort_on_exception = true` is a global setting so be aware that it might break other code in your app or it's dependencies that expects the default behavior. I'd opt for the `t.abort_on_exception = true` approach unless it's a very tiny script.

Comment: If this code is in a gem or will otherwise be called by code beyond your control, then the instance method isn't very helpful either, since you are effectively dictating abort behavior to the entire runtime, most of which you have no knowledge of, or (should have) control over.

Comment: Instead of saving the variable and then setting `t.abort_on_exception = true` you could also add `Thread.current.abort_on_exception = true` as the first (or any other) line of the thread content, which has my personal preference.

Answer (score 6):

```
Thread.class_eval do
  alias_method :initialize_without_exception_bubbling, :initialize
  def initialize(*args, &block)
    initialize_without_exception_bubbling(*args) {
      begin
        block.call
      rescue Exception => e
        Thread.main.raise e
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Voted down because this is just code with no explanations.  Needs comments, description of what it does, why, etc.

Comment: Also don't override ruby core classes. -1'd

Comment: I disagree with both comments.

Comment: The `Thread.main.raise e` works well to propagate the exception up the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Postponed exceptions processing (Inspired by @Jason Ling)

```
class SafeThread < Thread

  def initialize(*args, &block)
    super(*args) do
      begin
        block.call
      rescue Exception => e
        @exception = e
      end
    end
  end

  def join
    raise_postponed_exception
    super
    raise_postponed_exception
  end

  def raise_postponed_exception
    Thread.current.raise @exception if @exception
  end

end


puts :start

begin
  thread = SafeThread.new do
    raise 'error from sub-thread'
  end

  puts 'do something heavy before joining other thread'
  sleep 1

  thread.join
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Caught: #{e}"
end

puts 'proper end'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will wait for the first thread to either raise or return (and re-raise):

```
require 'thwait'
def wait_for_first_block_to_complete(*blocks)
  threads = blocks.map do |block|
    Thread.new do
      block.call
    rescue StandardError
      $!
    end
  end
  waiter = ThreadsWait.new(*threads)
  value = waiter.next_wait.value
  threads.each(&:kill)
  raise value if value.is_a?(StandardError)
  value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jason Ling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095316/handling-exceptions-raised-in-a-ruby-thread/10382899#10382899) will miss out any arguments passed to Thread.new. This will break Puma and other gems. To avoid this problem, you can use:

```
Thread.class_eval do
  alias_method :initialize_without_exception_bubbling, :initialize
  def initialize(*args, &block)
    initialize_without_exception_bubbling(*args) {
      begin
        block.call(*args)
      rescue Exception => e
        Thread.main.raise e
      end
    }
  end
end
```