# How to detect disconnected Unix Domain Socket in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm writing simple echo server/client using Unix Domain Socket in Ruby. Here are my codes:

server.rb

```
require 'socket'

# Listens server.sock and enters an infinite loop
Socket.unix_server_loop('server.sock') do |sock, addr|
  # When accepted a connection, creates a new thread
  puts "Accepted connection from:"
  Thread.new do
    loop do
      rs = IO.select([sock], [], [sock])
      p rs
      input = sock.gets.chomp
      puts "input = [#{input}]"
      sock.puts("response to #{input}")
    end
    puts "Thread quits."
    sock.close
  end
end

puts "Server quits."
```

client.rb

```
require 'socket'

UNIXSocket.open('server.sock') do |sock|
  5.times do |i|
    begin
      sock.puts "#{Time.now}: Hello #{i} from #{Process.pid}"
      puts "Recived " + sock.gets
      sleep 1
    rescue Errno::EPIPE => e
      puts "Connection closed."
      break
    end
  end
  sock.close
end

puts "Client quits."
```

They are working fine except that the server doesn't detect client quiting and it waits for the input forever. Although `select` returns the file descriptor (which means the descriptor is ready to read, from what I understand), `sock.gets` blocks. How can I detect disconnected sockets and make the server thread quit properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the connection is closed, `sock.gets` returns nil i.e.

```
input = sock.gets
break if input.nil?
input = input.chomp
```

should work.

For debug purposes

```
require 'socket'
Thread.abort_on_exception=true
```

could be used. The original code will then end because of

> undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

For more detail, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9095369/5781248).

Comment: Ahh, I tried checking empty string, but didn't come up with nil. It worked, thanks. But then, why my code didn't raise NoMethodError, though calling nil.chomp?

Comment: @aosho235 my guess is that `NoMethodError` was raised, but it was somehow discarded because it happened inside a thread.

Comment: Thanks again, @J.J. Hakala. By using `Thread.abort_on_exception = true`, Ruby printed the exception.