# Threading in Ruby. Alternative to ThreadPool

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Lets say I have 2 different tables that needed to be filled. Each table can have different number of source files. I want to fill the tables in parallel but each source file will be read consequently.
example: Table A: 3 source files, Table B: 1 source files

```
tables = {'A': [sourcefileA_1, sourcefileA_2,sourcefileA_3], 'B':[sourcefileB_1]}
threads = []
tables.each do |table,source_files|
 threads << Thread.new { do_something(table, source_files)}
end
threads.each(&:join)
def do_something(table, source_files)
 source_files.each do |s_file|
 #do something
end
```

So, the number of threads depends on the number of tables I have. Lets say now I have 500.000 tables and just a normal Mac Pro. I thought of using *ThreadPool*, however, if some error occurs in the *thread* it is not shown. In comparison if I use just threads the error is still shown.Is there any gem that can help me to use thread pool and that will throw an error if it occurs in one of the threads.

Regarding not showing the error, consider following:

```
require 'thread/pool' # from the ruby-thread gem
pool = Thread.pool(4)
pool.process do 
 puts(b)
end
```

*b* is not specified but it does not show me the normal error message.

Comment: the question title is too broad; however the issue getting errors from Thread.pool is salient. Perhaps you should update the title to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

First,

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095316/handling-exceptions-raised-in-a-ruby-thread) out (the answer) about error handling.

second, there is a nice gem called [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) which have many aspects of multi threading in other languages implemented in ruby.

Another issue to consider is that ruby is not really concurrent, because of the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock). But you got fibers, which do good job for your case, async IO.

Comment: The answer about error handling states: 
_If you don't set this variable to true, exception will only be raised when you call Thread#join or Thread#value for the thread._

I do join the threads, so I do catch the errors. Also the answer considers the usage of `thread`, in my case `Thread.pool(4)`does not throw the exceptions. So, this answer does not help me.

Regarding GIL, I am not sure I understand you correctly. I did a benchmarking with threads and without. It was much faster with threads. Why did I get such benchmarking results?

Comment: regarding benchmark, its possible that whenever you query external service (db and file) there is a context switch till the io returns.

Comment: could you please elaborate? A context switch can lead to a longer process time, but according to your message it did speed up the process

Comment: so, basically what I am doing wight now is that I am NOT running the tables in parallel, right (not on different processors)?